# how to change my source directory

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just changed my username and name of my home directory. Now I cannot use catkin_make because the source directory's name has been changed. How can I update, or change my source directory of catkin_ws?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100381/how-to-change-my-source-directory/) by [Jessica](https://answers.ros.org/users/8731/jessica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried removing catkin_ws/{build, devel} and running catkin_make again?

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3